# How to apply styleable selector color to custom drawable in custom Button subclass?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-styles, android-selector

I have create a custom `Button` subclass which performs some custom drawing and adds some additional features.

Now I would like to add the possibility to show a custom drawable/image/icon on that `Button`. Adding the image is not a big deal, but how can I tint this icon in different colors depending on the current state?

I tried to use a `ColorStateList` to tint the drawable with the current state-color, but it does not work: The drawable is always drawn with its own, unchanged color.

I assume that the applied color filter is not used when converting the drawable into a bitmap. Is this correct? How can I fix this?

This is my code:

**Layout**

```
<com.example.UI.MyButton
     ...
     mc:iconSrc="@drawable/someIcon"
     mc:iconTintColor="@drawable/button_selector_colors"/>
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<declare-styleable name="MyButton">
    <attr name="iconSrc" format="reference" />
    <attr name="iconTintColor" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

**button_selector_colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:color="@color/myPressed"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/mySelected"/>
    <item android:color="@color/myDefault"/>
</selector>
```

**MyButton.java**

```
public class MyButton extends Button {
    private Drawable mIconDrawable;
    private ColorStateList mIconTintColor;

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyButton);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.getIndexCount(); ++i) {
            int attr = array.getIndex(i);
            switch (attr) {
                case R.styleable.MyButton_iconSrc:
                    mIconDrawable = array.getDrawable(attr);
                    break;
                case R.styleable.MyButton_iconTintColor:
                    mIconTintColor = array.getColorStateList(attr);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        array.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        ...

        if (mIconDrawable != null) {
            ... // calc position, etc.

            if (mIconTintColor != null) {
                mIconDrawable.mutate();
                int[] stateSet = getDrawableState();
                int defaultColor = Color.BLACK; //mIconTintColor.getDefaultColor();

                int stateColor = mIconTintColor.getColorForState(stateSet, defaultColor);

                mIconDrawable.setColorFilter(stateColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }

            Bitmap icon = drawableToBitmap(mIconDrawable);
            canvas.drawBitmap(icon, ...);
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you are seeing, "more restores than saves", means that you have called `Canvas.restore()` more times than `Canvas.save()`. You must have a matching restore for each save.

You don't show the saves and restores in your code, but make sure that they balance for all execution paths.

---

The underflow condition is cured. I think that you have a sizing/placement problem. Instead of converting the icon for your button to a bitmap, try the following:

```
mIconDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
mIconDrawable.draw(canvas);
```

You might be getting hung up in the conversion. If you really want to create the bitmap, I don't think that the intrinsic width and height are what you need. Try the following:

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable, int width, int height) {
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Then call and draw the icon as follows:

```
Bitmap icon = drawableToBitmap(mIconDrawable, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
canvas.drawBitmap(icon, 0, 0, null);
```

Comment: Thank, this was just too obvious of course :-) The exception is solved but the main problem stays the same: The color filter is not applied...